# Oracle Performance Slow with Select Union From Dual in Join Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlperformance

The below original query takes 6 seconds for execution. But when I remove most of select union from dual in joint statement (just keep 1) then the query just takes 1.2 seconds for execution. Can someone tell me what the issue is and how to fix this?

## **Original Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.RNUM                                                                     as ROW_NUM,
                b.MAX_ROWNUM,
                b.ta_or_od_id,
                b.lnk_od_id,
                b.bussiness_unit,
                b.CIF,
                b.pf_id,
                b.grp_tsk_status,
                b.grp_tsk_type_and_status,
                ta.src_sys,
                ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE,
                ta.mod_at,
                tr.ORDER_ID
FROM (SELECT 1                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IABX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00019'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IACX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00020'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla1|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 3                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IADX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00021'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla2|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 4                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAEX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00022'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla3|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 5                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAFX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00023'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla4|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 6                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAGX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00024'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla5|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 7                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAHX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00025'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla6|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL) b
         JOIN tsk_ref tr on case
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is not null and regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                                            '^' || tr.od_id ||
                                                                                            '_|_' || tr.od_id || '$')
                                            then 1
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                             nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id then 1
                                        else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                    NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
         JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN rt_saving_cf rsc
                         ON rsc.rul_id = tr.rul_id AND (rsc.chn = tr.chn OR rsc.chn = 'ALL') AND
                            rsc.ex_only = ta.so AND rsc.act = 'Y'
WHERE tr.tsk_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl_id
                     FROM (SELECT tr.tsk_id, tr.pr_tsk_id
                           FROM (SELECT 1                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IABX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00019'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 2                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IACX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00020'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla1|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 3                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IADX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00021'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla2|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 4                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IAEX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00022'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla3|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 5                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IAFX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00023'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla4|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 6                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IAGX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00024'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla5|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 7                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IAHX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00025'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla6|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL) b join tsk_ref tr on case when b.lnk_od_id is not null and
                                                                   regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                               '^' || tr.od_id || '_|_' ||
                                                                               tr.od_id || '$') then 1
                                                              when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                                                   nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id
                                                                  then 1
                                                              else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                                          NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
                                    JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
                           WHERE TA.tsk_status IN ('Open', 'Rejected')
                             AND UPPER(TR.pr_id) IN ('MA179234')) UNPIVOT (sl_id FOR COL IN (tsk_id, pr_id)))
ORDER BY b.RNUM, b.ta_or_od_id, ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE ASC NULLS LAST, ta.mod_at DESC;
```

## **Query after removing most of select union from dual in join statement:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.RNUM                                                                     as ROW_NUM,
                b.MAX_ROWNUM,
                b.ta_or_od_id,
                b.lnk_od_id,
                b.bussiness_unit,
                b.CIF,
                b.pf_id,
                b.grp_tsk_status,
                b.grp_tsk_type_and_status,
                ta.src_sys,
                ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE,
                ta.mod_at,
                tr.ORDER_ID
FROM (SELECT 1                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IABX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00019'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IACX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00020'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla1|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 3                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IADX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00021'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla2|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 4                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAEX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00022'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla3|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 5                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAFX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00023'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla4|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 6                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAGX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00024'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla5|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 7                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAHX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00025'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla6|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL) b
         JOIN tsk_ref tr on case
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is not null and regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                                            '^' || tr.od_id ||
                                                                                            '_|_' || tr.od_id || '$')
                                            then 1
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                             nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id then 1
                                        else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                    NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
         JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN rt_saving_cf rsc
                         ON rsc.rul_id = tr.rul_id AND (rsc.chn = tr.chn OR rsc.chn = 'ALL') AND
                            rsc.ex_only = ta.so AND rsc.act = 'Y'
WHERE tr.tsk_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl_id
                     FROM (SELECT tr.tsk_id, tr.pr_tsk_id
                           FROM (SELECT 1                                      AS RNUM,
                                        'ABC345IABX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
                                        NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
                                        '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
                                        '00019'                                AS CIF,
                                        NULL                                   AS pf_id,
                                        7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
                                        'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
                                        'Tesla|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
                                 FROM DUAL) b join tsk_ref tr on case when b.lnk_od_id is not null and
                                                                   regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                               '^' || tr.od_id || '_|_' ||
                                                                               tr.od_id || '$') then 1
                                                              when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                                                   nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id
                                                                  then 1
                                                              else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                                          NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
                                    JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
                           WHERE TA.tsk_status IN ('Open', 'Rejected')
                             AND UPPER(TR.pr_id) IN ('MA179234')) UNPIVOT (sl_id FOR COL IN (tsk_id, pr_id)))
ORDER BY b.RNUM, b.ta_or_od_id, ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE ASC NULLS LAST, ta.mod_at DESC;
```

I would like to speed up the query.

Comment: Before spending too much time on performance tuning, I recommend changing the query to avoid repeating logic. The sections with the 7 rows joined to TSK_REF and TSK_ACT looks exactly the same and can be put into a `WITH tasks AS ...` and then referenced twice. That change would also give Oracle the option of running the query only once, storing the results in a temp table, and re-using that temp table. Also, since you know the 7 rows will be distinct, replace the `UNION` with `UNION ALL` to avoid running distinct operations. Then generate an execution plan with a `GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS` hint.

Comment: I agree with jon heller
Also consider using temporary table as variables, this kind of query will be such a pain to work on, for the person comming after you.

By using temporary table, you can perform a step by step process to manipulate your data, and debug it

.At the end you just have to drop the temp tables

The biggest advantage for performance is that temp table support indexes...joining with other tables will be ultra fast

Comment: I second the above - this method of using dual to pass in row data isn't an acceptable method for anything but a quick demo of a concept on SO, not for real programming. It creates massive SQL cursors, is unsharable because every execution is a different literal SQL, and causes problems for Oracle's internal memory management. Take rows from tables, not as literals in your SQL. As for the performance issue, nobody can say exactly what's going on without a lot more information, which is hard to convey in a forum like this.

Comment: @JonHeller Yes, you are right the 7 selects from dual are the same in two parts. About the temp table solution, please correct me if I am wrong, because the 7 selects from dual they are the dynamic queries which are generated by a Java API after the user sends a request to the Java API from the UI and our UI is being used by a lot of users so if we create a temp table and insert that dynamic data into the temp table we will face with another difficult issue is how to control that temp table.

Comment: @DJRemixMusic, I'm afraid this Java API is not properly designed to work with Oracle if it insists on generating these union all queries like this. That is simply not an acceptable way to interact with the database. I do not allow this in my org (we see this kind of thing far more than we should) and always require developers to rewrite it when we run into it. It's about a lot more than merely your performance, it's about database health. I strongly suggest considering another product.

Comment: @PaulW so do you think what should be the solution for the **select union from dual **  in this SQL. Is there any way to put the **select union from dual ** to a variable then we can use it in somewhere.

Comment: @DJRemixMusic, inserts rows into a table, then query using the table. Use bind variables, not literals, for the insert.

Answer (score 0):

### Simplify with a Common Table Expression

Before you start tuning, simplify the query with a common table expression (CTE). Also, replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` whenever you know the rows are unique, to avoid sorting. The below code only puts the new rows in a CTE, but your real version should also include the duplicate joins in the CTE.

```
WITH NEW_ROWS AS
(
      SELECT 1                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IABX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00019'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IACX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00020'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla1|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IADX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00021'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla2|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAEX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00022'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla3|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAFX'                            AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00023'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla4|Open'                           AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 6                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAGX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00024'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla5|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 7                                      AS RNUM,
             'ABC345IAHX'                           AS ta_or_od_id,
             NULL                                   AS lnk_od_id,
             '0001'                                 AS bussiness_unit,
             '00025'                                AS CIF,
             NULL                                   AS pf_id,
             7                                      AS MAX_ROWNUM,
             'Open'                                 AS grp_tsk_status,
             'Tesla6|Open'                          AS grp_tsk_type_and_status
      FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT b.RNUM                                                                     as ROW_NUM,
                b.MAX_ROWNUM,
                b.ta_or_od_id,
                b.lnk_od_id,
                b.bussiness_unit,
                b.CIF,
                b.pf_id,
                b.grp_tsk_status,
                b.grp_tsk_type_and_status,
                ta.src_sys,
                ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE,
                ta.mod_at,
                tr.ORDER_ID
FROM new_rows b
         JOIN tsk_ref tr on case
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is not null and regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                                            '^' || tr.od_id ||
                                                                                            '_|_' || tr.od_id || '$')
                                            then 1
                                        when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                             nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id then 1
                                        else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                    NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
         JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN rt_saving_cf rsc
                         ON rsc.rul_id = tr.rul_id AND (rsc.chn = tr.chn OR rsc.chn = 'ALL') AND
                            rsc.ex_only = ta.so AND rsc.act = 'Y'
WHERE tr.tsk_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sl_id
                     FROM (SELECT tr.tsk_id, tr.pr_tsk_id
                           FROM new_rows b join tsk_ref tr on case when b.lnk_od_id is not null and
                                                                   regexp_like(b.lnk_od_id,
                                                                               '^' || tr.od_id || '_|_' ||
                                                                               tr.od_id || '$') then 1
                                                              when b.lnk_od_id is null and
                                                                   nvl(tr.od_id, tr.tsk_id) = b.ta_or_od_id
                                                                  then 1
                                                              else 0 end = 1 AND b.bussiness_unit = tr.bussiness_unit AND
                                                          NVL(b.pf_id, 'NULL') = NVL(tr.pf_id, 'NULL')
                                    JOIN tsk_act ta ON tr.tsk_id = ta.tsk_id
                           WHERE TA.tsk_status IN ('Open', 'Rejected')
                             AND UPPER(TR.pr_id) IN ('MA179234')) UNPIVOT (sl_id FOR COL IN (tsk_id, pr_id)))
ORDER BY b.RNUM, b.ta_or_od_id, ta.DUE_DATE_VALUE ASC NULLS LAST, ta.mod_at DESC;
```

### Temp table

When I said temp table in my comment, I was referring to the temp table that Oracle will likely automatically create for you, as seen in the beginning of this explain plan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                             |     1 |   776 |    32   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D66C5_AADEAE83 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL                             |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     FAST DUAL                            |                             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
...
```

It may be a good idea to create an Oracle global temporary table instead, but that decision depends on several factors. A global temporary table requires more work to manage the object, including dealing with statistics on a rapidly changing object. On the plus side, the query will always be the same, which reduces parsing time and makes the query easier to manage and tune.

If this query only runs once an hour, and the CTE is good enough to help with performance, then it's fine to hard code everything. If the query runs 10 times a second, and creates persistent performance problems, then you should probably spend the time to make the global temporary table. (Or, alternatively, you could use an oracle type and collection to pass in multiple rows of data.)

### Tuning

When you've simplified and narrowed down the choices, you'll want to tune by generating an execution plan with the real numbers. I recommend either the `GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS` or `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR`. Those two tools produce much more useful results than a mere explain plan. Edit your question with the results and we can take another look at the problem.

Comment: Your solution by using `UNION ALL` and `WITH NEW_ROWS AS` improved the query execution from 5.5 secs to 1.3 secs. Thank you so much @Jon Heller